# How to choose the error concealment method for openh264?

Tags: openh264

What does these error concealment enum means for openh264?  Are there any documentation for them?

```
 typedef enum {
      ERROR_CON_DISABLE = 0,
      ERROR_CON_FRAME_COPY,
      ERROR_CON_SLICE_COPY,
      ERROR_CON_FRAME_COPY_CROSS_IDR,
      ERROR_CON_SLICE_COPY_CROSS_IDR,
      ERROR_CON_SLICE_COPY_CROSS_IDR_FREEZE_RES_CHANGE,
      ERROR_CON_SLICE_MV_COPY_CROSS_IDR,
      ERROR_CON_SLICE_MV_COPY_CROSS_IDR_FREEZE_RES_CHANGE
    } ERROR_CON_IDC;
```